# What was the author's intention in 1 Clement 30:5?

Tags: authorial-intent, 1-clement

I have researched various translations of **1 Clement 30:5** and would be thankful if anyone could expound what is meant by:

*"Blessed is the offspring of a woman that liveth but a short time. Be not thou abundant in words."*

*alternate translation:

*"Doth he that is born of woman and liveth but for a short time think himself to be blessed? Be not abundant in speech."*

Comment: We sometimes allow questions on extra-Biblical texts. See [What texts are open for examination?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/687/2757) I'm not sure about this question.

Comment: It seems to echo the ancient adage [ars longa, vita brevis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars_longa,_vita_brevis).

Comment: To me 1 Clement falls cleanly into 'Secondary Texts' as in the Meta cited above. It's literally a text by a disciple of Peter, written within a similar date range to the New Testament. I'd see it as clearly in the scope of new testament scholarship, and also relevant to understanding how biblical texts were understood by the earliest generations of Christians.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the text of 1 Clem 30:5 -

> ευλογημενος γεννητος γυναικος ολιγοβιος. μη πολυς εν ρημασιν γινου.

Here is the respected Michael W Holmes' 1992 translation:

> Blessed is the one born of woman who has a short life.  Do not be
> overly talkative.

Lightfoot's older translations has:

> Blessed is the offspring of a woman that liveth but a short time. Be
> not thou abundant in words.

The Roberts-Donaldson translation is also similar:

> Blessed is he that is born of woman, who lives but a short time: be
> not given to much speaking.

I am at a loss to understand why Charles Hoole translates with a question as in:

> doth he that is born of woman and liveth but for a short time think
> himself to be blessed? Be not abundant in speech.

All I can assume is this might be an interpretive translation to soften the effect of this jarring statement.  It also helps to see this in the surrounding verses (V2-8):

> "For God," says [the Scripture], "resists the proud, but gives grace
> to the humble." Let us cleave, then, to those to whom grace has been
> given by God. Let us clothe ourselves with concord and humility, ever
> exercising self-control, standing far off from all whispering and
> evil-speaking, being justified by our works, and not our words. For
> [the Scripture] says, "He that speaks much, shall also hear much in
> answer. And does he that is ready in speech deem himself righteous?
> **Blessed is he that is born of woman, who lives but a short time: be not given to much speaking**." Let our praise be in God, and not of
> ourselves; for God hates those who commend themselves. Let testimony
> to our good deeds be borne by others, as it was in the case of our
> righteous forefathers. Boldness, and arrogance, and audacity belong to
> those that are accursed of God; but moderation, humility, and meekness
> to such as are blessed by Him.

V5 may be an allusion to some parts of Scripture that discuss old age and its aches and pains, disabilities (eg, loss of hearing and loss of sight), as well as advancing decrepitude generally.  A person who dies young does not endure the difficulties of the geriatric.